# how do I stop Facebook from correcting my log in email address

Tags: email, facebook

A year ago, I deactivated my Facebook account.  My husband's account can be accessed (and is automatically) from both his laptop and mine.  I would like 1) stop having his page automatically open on my computer and 2) reactivate my own account.  I've managed to achieve the 1st step.  The problem I can't get past is that my email address is only one letter different from his.  When I go to log in to reactive my old account, the login page "self-corrects" to his email, asking for his password.

Comment: This is about remembered logins in a browser, not about Facebook itself. For this reason it is not off-topic, though it's very likely a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer says, this is a function of your browser. It's normally called auto-fill. Your browser can remember username/password combinations for most systems you log in to.

Most browsers also have ways to delete separate auto-fill entries. The actual ways differ per browser, though. I googled a bit and assembled some info below. Never know who may read this later :)

---

Deleting auto-fill entries in the **Internet Explorer browser** (got this from [here](http://contests.about.com/od/sweepstakes101/qt/clearautofill.htm)):

1. Double-click in the text field so the drop-down box of auto-fill options appears.
2. Hold your mouse over the option that you want to remove from auto-fill so that it's highlighted. (Don't click on it.)
3. Press your delete key. The option should be deleted from your auto-fill.

---

Deleting Auto-Fill Entries in the **Firefox browser** (from the same site)

1. Follow the same steps as in Internet Explorer above, except that you hold down shift while pressing delete in the third step.

---

If you're using the **Chrome browser** here is Google [support](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893?hl=en):

1. Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
2. Select Settings.
3. Click Show advanced settings and find the "Passwords and forms" section.
4. Click Manage Autofill settings.
5. To edit an existing entry, double-click it in the list to open the editing dialog.
6. To delete an existing entry, select it from the list and click the x that appears at the end of the row.

---

If you are using the **Safari 6 browser** on a Mac, here is Apple [support](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11874) to the rescue:

1. Open Safari if it is not already open.
2. Choose Safari > Preferences, and then click AutoFill.
3. Deselect “Using info from my Contacts card” and “Other forms.”
4. If you have OS X Lion, deselect “Using info from my Address Book card” and “Other forms.”
5. Next to “Other forms,” click Edit. A list of websites where you normally fill in information such as your name and email address appears.
6. Select individual websites and click Remove, or click Remove All.
7. Click Done.

---

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

After auto-fill in the login prompts, just backspace the password field empty, click into the email field and fix the one letter difference, then supply that accounts password.

Auto-fill is actually a function of your browser, not facebook.  You may also be able to access the browsers setting to delete the stored login info, Can't tell you how tho because we don't know what browser you are using.